# Issue while run of Same @Test method mutiple times with different parameter in same <test>

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng.xml

I have a problem while running my @ Test in order i want multiple times in single test. Basically my framework is designed such that i have some number of @Test methods in different classes and i call them in order i want to create a basic test case in my xml file. But when i try to call same @Test method , it is not taking order i want and is running only once

For eg: i have two classes

```
 class A{
     @Test ({parameter blah })
     public void foo(){}
 }

  class B{
    @Test ({parameter bloo})
    public void doo(){}
  }
```

I want to call in xml in following way:-

```
    <test> demotest
    <class name="A"><parameter name="blah" value="somevalue"</class>
    <class name="B"><parameter name="bloo" value="xyzvalue"</class>
    <class name="A"><parameter name="blah" value="somethervalue"</class>
     </test>
```

And i want output -

```
   somevalue
   xyzvalue
   someothervalue
```

But it is running class A only once with someothervalue(i am assuming it is taking parameter with respect to alphabet order ).

How can i get my @test method run as per i want twice in same test case with two diff parameters , it is just same method with different input so i dont want to include seperate method/class.

Let me know if more info is required

Answer (score 0):

use preserve order, then tests will run as specified.

```
  <test name="Test" preserve-order="true">
```

Also running same class twice in same test is not possible.

Comment: thanks! but did not work!! :( , still taking with value "someothervalue"

Comment: could you paste total xml file so we can try similar way

Comment: it is project specific , and i an unable to add here can i inbox you

Comment: is it a limitation in testNG that we cannot run same @Test multiple times in single run

Comment: Yes, its limitation https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/testng-users/caR18BmUJlM

Comment: @CodingGirl1 provide your requirement, people can suggest best possible ways

Comment: Yes , my requirement is i have an @test login method for my salesforce application ,which can be logged in with different user types by defining username as parameter. For a particular test scenario i want to login ,do some stuff save the info using testContext methods , logout and login again with diff user and work on same stuff. But i am unable to call same login method with different user(defined a parameter) in single test. If i create different test case the info will be lost because it is not same test. Hope it is clear!

Comment: @CodingGirl1 see calling same class/method twice in testng.xml is not possible but as one class/method you can do it by passing 2 parameters means two users instead of one. So hve one method only for login as user..doing stuff and longing as another user.

Answer (score 0):

I have understood that there is limitation here , we cannot call same method twice in single test , i created a workaround of storing temp values in an excel sheet and retreiving them and creating group of test dependent on each other , know its a bad practice but cant help!!. Hope testng does something about this limitation